# Something like unity but for C++ programmers

Tags: c++, desktop-application, game-engine

is there anything similar to unity but with the difference that instead of javascript I can use C++?

Comment: "Unity has extensive support for Plugins, which are libraries of native code written in C, C++, Objective-C, etc." Seems using C++ with Unity is even easier than Javascript (which isn't native)

Comment: #MSalters hi, that would be just fantastic, will surely check this out. Thank you very much +1

Comment: #MSalters I've checked that out and indeed you can use plug ins. Few points to note, notably one, you still cannot call them directly, but instead you have to use C# which tells me that performance will be c# not c++. This isn't acceptable.

Comment: the specific quote (libraries of native code) makes it entirely clear that you can use C++ directly, but C# only indirectly (you have to host the CLR, which is the native code that executes C# code)

Comment: @MSalters I think that you misunderstood what they are saying. You cannot use C++ directly. You have to call them via C#.

Comment: @smallB, What could you possibly be attempting to do as far as logic is concerned where you are losing performance to a point that you consider the scripting languages unacceptable?  Simply put considering that hundreds of games are developed using unity and none of them have problems it has to be your own poor design.  You shouldn't blame other languages or other peoples opinions because of your own deficiencies.  You shouldn't need the language to pick up your slack, if your logic is performing poorly that is your fault not the 15% overhead of the JIT / CRL process.

Comment: You can use C++ if you have pro but you'll have to use **their** C#/JavaScript for adapting/porting.

Answer (score 2):

It is funny, I was looking to learn a little bit of unity as I seen it as requirement for some postings... and I found this question.

I think Ogre3D is great... it may be what you are looking for. 
here is the link ogre3d.org

Ogre3D is what I used. http://www.ogre3d.org/

Comment: hey, thanks for your answer. Will try Ogre3d. I played with unity for a while but I just cannot stand it's performance. I need C++.

Answer (score 1):

It is somewhat of a misconception that Unity uses Javascript. The so-called Javascript used in Unity is actually a dialect of Javascript that is CLI-compatible and is not exactly the same as the official Javascript. Also, you are not limited to using Javascript in Unity. You can also use C#, which is similar to C++ and Java in some ways or the less commonly used Boo script.

Personally, I would recommend using C# in Unity because it is very powerful and allows calling of native C/C++ functions via P/Invoke. Here is a link to the use of plugins:
http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/Manual/Plugins.html

Link to list of Game Engines. Please take your time to read and consider them:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_game_engines

Comment: Why are you restricted to C++? I do not think you can find a game-engine that is as easy to use as Unity that uses a lower-level language like C++.

Comment: C++ (modern) isn't low level. Absrtaction is on par with C# (and higher) but performance is unreachable for C#.

Comment: -1 because: your edit is what I call "cheap shot". I know how to use google and I am also aware of wikipedia. The whole purpose of me coming here to stackoverflow is to ask precise answer and get concrete answer. Doing it your way (the linux way as I like to call it) every question can be answered in similar way: read manual, check web, look into standard etc. You've missed whole point.

Comment: continue:But if you would dissagree with me and reasons for downvoting you, here is another: you gave answer to the question I didn't ask. My question is: "is there anything similar to unity but with the difference that instead of javascript I can use C++? " and you answered to the question: what are there game engines available. That's why -1 ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you want accessibility offered by Unity, C++ is certainly wrong choice. Much better would be interpreted/script language, such as Python. They are more flexible in terms of working in web browser/many os-es.

Comment: I'm really not interested in scripting languages. For performance reasons

Comment: scripting languages show exceptional performance nowadays. I would really suggest you take a look at them.

Comment: please don't. The point is that nothing compares to C++ (or natives in general) for technical reasons. Nothing. I'd suggest that you try to look at them and compare with scripting languages ;)

Comment: around 15% overhead in JIT mode is enough for games.

Comment: Please don't. I'd rather spend this 15% on something useful. Seriously, stop living in coockoo land. And as a side note, why would I want to use some inmature, low performing scripting language if I have beatiful, new out of the box C++11 which is unbeatable? Why would I want to do such thing?

Comment: Your opinion seems biased. Also, C++11 is more immature than Lua or Python, FYI.

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in targetting mobile platforms then [Marmalade](http://www.madewithmarmalade.com/) might be a good fit.

Answer (score 0):

[Panda3D](http://www.panda3d.org/) It's not a think compared to Unity, but it can work as a web plugin, cross-platform. It has a lack of IDE, but it is opensource.

As far as I know, there is no need to use JavaScript or Boo with Unity, and there is nothing wrong with C# acting like script language ( which is really hard with C++ ).

Answer (score 0):

as a unity developer, I liked to add c++ to by knowledge base as all AAA games are made by C++ and I was looking for something like unity but for CPP. the only good cpp engine is unreal that doesn't really support c++. the language is a dialect of c++ and there are big differences. like very

- rare usages of pointer and references
- more syntaxes like c# attributes(cpp has not attribute)
  ...

so you don't learn memory management. the nearest thing that I could find was COCOS2dx as the whole framework is written in pure standard c++ and many libraries like UI and Physics are already added. you can write your own engine and editor with it.

Answer (score 0):

Unreal Engine uses C++
default standard is C++14

https://www.unrealengine.com